# Lambda Function to Call Database

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS/Lambda/Amazon Connect and trying my way around it. I have the below code to request Information from my dynamoDB table and update the table in case of a new entry. My issue is that the function only seems to run the except part and completely ignores the try. Need to understand why

**CODE**

```
import boto3
import json
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Lambda Trigger event: " + json.dumps(event))

    try:

        phoneNumber = event['Details']['ContactData']['CustomerEndpoint']['Address']
        print("Customer Phone Number : " + phoneNumber)

        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='ap-southeast-2')

        table = dynamodb.Table('data_dip_table')

        response = table.get_item(Key={
                                'phone-number': phoneNumber
                                })
        print("dynamodb response: " + json.dumps(response))

        if 'Item' in response:
            # TODO: Match Found
            print("Phone number match found!")

            firstName = response['Item']['first-name']
            print("Customer First Name: " + firstName)

            welcomeMessage = 'Welcome' + firstName + ' to Our data dip'
            print("welcome message :" + welcomeMessage)

            return {'welcomeMessage' : welcomeMessage }

        else:
            print("Phone Number was not Found")

            return { 'welcomeMessage' : 'Welcome!' }

    except Exception as e:
        print("An Error Has Occurred")
        print(e)
        return {'welcomeMessage' : 'Welcome !'}
```

**My Output is**

Response:
{
  "welcomeMessage": "Welcome !"
}

Request ID:
"0d9b6bf6-62f8-4385-81f0-f1d36ee489c8"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 0d9b6bf6-62f8-4385-81f0-f1d36ee489c8 Version: $LATEST
Lambda Trigger event: {}
An Error Has Occurred
'Details'
END RequestId: 0d9b6bf6-62f8-4385-81f0-f1d36ee489c8

I have an entry for my phone number in the DD table but still get an error.Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event` object is empty. Check this line in CloudWatchLogs:

```
Lambda Trigger event: {}
```

Your code is definitely not ignoring the `try` block, however, on the first line of your try block, you have `phoneNumber = event['Details']['ContactData']['CustomerEndpoint']['Address']` which automatically fails because your event is empty, therefore redirecting the execution to the `except` block.

How is this function being triggered? If you are doing it manually from AWS's Console, you will have to create a test event that contains the body that your method expects.

Comment: Thanks Thales. The function is triggered from Amazon connect when a call is made to the connect number. The first step of my cal flow is invoking this function. And I've tried calling my connect number too, it fails and plays my error message.

Comment: I see. I don't have experience with AWS Connect myself, so I can't help you much there. But do keep in mind that you are facing this issue because the event is empty. Figure that out and you'll be fine.

In the meantime, try to trigger it manually from the console with the JSON that you want so you can actually test to see if your code works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Thales. I figured it out, thanks to your recommendations as well. Turns out a simple permissions issue and apparently AWS logging is not that good. So as you suggested I used a json test event to verify what my method was expecting and helped me resolve it.